# How does var obj=new function(){} work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have this code:

```
var obj=new function(){
  this.var=null;
  this.fun=function(funVar){
    console.log('funVar: ',funVar);
  }
  console.log('init',this);
  this.fun('fun');
};
obj.var='Something';
obj;
```

In the console log I have `var==null` and also `var=='something'`:
[image]

I don't understand what is happening.

I was hoping to do something like `obj;` to initiate the object. I know how to do `obj={init:function(){}}` then use `obj.init()`, I was just experimenting and now I'm curios.

Comment: `obj;` by itself can’t initiate anything, because it’s just an object, not a function call. `new function(){};` constructs an object from an anonymous function. It’s like `new SomeConstructor();` or the equivalent `new SomeConstructor;`, but with an anonymous function.

Comment: do you know anything about `var xxx = function() { ... }`;

Comment: Someone answer then delete it afterwards that said is about the scope of `var`, there are actually two `var` variables the `obj.var='something'` and the one inside the function.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

1. Functions are first-class values in JavaScript, just like objects, arrays, etc. So, you can write `var foo = function(){};` which will create a new function value, and place a reference to that value in the variable `foo`. As with any function, **you must put parentheses after the reference to invoke the function**:

   ```js
   var a = function(){ console.log('hi') };
   var b = function(){ console.log('bye') };
   var c = a;
   a;   // does nothing useful. similar to `42;` or `true;` as a statement
   a(); // "hi"
   c(); // "hi"
   b(); // "bye"

   console.log(typeof a); // "function"

   console.log(a==b); // false
   console.log(a==c); // true

   b = a;
   b(); // "hi"
   console.log(a==b); // true
   ```
2. Functions values can have custom properties placed on them, like JavaScript objects. For example:

   ```js
   function bar(){
     // arguments.callee gives the function value being called
     arguments.callee.callCount++; 
   }
   bar.callCount=0; // I just made up a new property!
   bar();
   bar();
   bar();
   console.log( bar.callCount ) // 3
   ```
3. When you use a function as a *constructor* in JavaScript by using the `new` keyword, the runtime (1) allocates a new object, (2) runs the function with this new objects as the `this` scope, and (3) returns that new object (not whatever the function returned).

   So: `var x = new bar();` creates a new empty object, invokes the `bar` function with that object as the `this` scope, and then puts a reference to that object into the variable `x`. Note that this new object is *different* from the function value. You can have a property with the same name, but different values, on different objects:

   ```js
   function jim(){
     this.jam = "my jam";
   }
   jim.jam = "shared jam"; // a custom property on the function

   var jm1 = new jim();
   var jm2 = new jim();
   console.log(jm1.jam); // my jam
   console.log(jm2.jam); // my jam
   console.log(jim.jam); // shared jam

   jm2.jam = "special jam";
   console.log(jm1.jam); // my jam
   console.log(jm2.jam); // special jam
   console.log(jim.jam); // shared jam
   ```